# Adding jPlayer to Magento site

Tags: magento, jplayer

I've got a simple, working demo page using jPlayer, which I built using the following guide:
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-8-audio/

That was pretty straight forward.

Now I'm looking for instructions on how to make the necessary `<head>` tag modifications such that I can have jPlayer show up on product pages in Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Javascript to the page head by using an `addJs` action. If you search the Magento site for `addjs head` you can see examples of how people have done it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for following output:  http://audiosample.wmdextensions.com/index.php/dj-disco.html

html5 audio sample player will allow you to play samples of downloadable product.

you will find more info about it [here](http://wmdextensions.com)

i hope this would help you.